# Budget data model best practice

Tags: architecture, design, data-model

Our requirment is to be add a budget module in Salesforce on the opportunity, that would have years and items. A best description for that is like this excel table:

[image: Excel example]

Our current approach is to have 2 custom objects related to the opportunity - one for years and one for items, and then a third object that connects them as a junction object:

[image]

Is this solution best practice?

Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I would think of like this:

`Budget Record` object will have 2 `picklist` fields naming `Budget Year` and `Budget Item`

And this `Budget Record` will be linked to `Opportunity`.

This way you can build `summary` or `matrix` reports on the `Budget Record` object considering the grouping on either `Budget Item` or `Budget Year`

Otherwise, creating a `custom report type` considering all 4 objects would be challenging.

Comment: Interesting idea. how then would we add budget amounts? adding a picklist value for each amount?

Comment: Budget amount will be based on Budget Year and Budget Item for each record